# How to test redux selector in Jest?

Tags: react-redux, jestjs, react-functional-component

I want to test the following selector:

```
export const getApp = (): IApp | null => {
  return useSelector<IState, IApp | null>((state) => state.appState.app);
};
```

This is the test:

```
import { appSelectors, getApp } from '../appSelectors';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { IApp } from '...common...interfaces';

let store: any = null;
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

const createMockStore = () => {
  store = mockStore(testsStore.initialState);
};

describe('apps selectors', () => {
  test('getApp', () => {
    const mockedApp: IApp = {
      id: 'mocked_id',
      name: 'mocked_id',
    };
    
    // ... >> modify the testsStore.initialState here ...
    createMockStore();

    expect(getApp()).toEqual(mockedApp);
  });
});
```

This is the error I get:
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen

```
for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

       7 |
       8 | export const getApp = (): IApp | null => {
    >  9 |   return useSelector<IState, IApp | null>((state) => state.appState.app);
         |          ^
      10 | };
```

How can I test this selector?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a testing framework? Use it to render the component. You can't call it because it's not a regular function.

Comment: @EstusFlask,  only way to test selector is by using component??     I'm using Jest/Enzym.    so, for this, I can use dummy component also, right?    will such testing be considered for coverage?     thank you.

Comment: You can expose `(state) => state.appState.app` selector function outside a component to reuse or test separately from React part. It's `useSelector` hook that is supposed to be called inside a component. `getApp` is what's called custom hook, and yes, it needs to be tested with dummy component.

Comment: Ok, dummy component will be created - and how can I test the return value of the selector?   it's a functional component - can't test any state/value in it...

Answer (score -1):

`(state) => state.appState.app` function is a selector, it can be extracted and tested separately, but since it's simple, it can be tested together with `getApp`.

`getApp` and `useSelector` are [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html), they are supposed to be called by React renderer and not directly. This needs to be done with dummy component. Since a developer has full control over it, the value needs to be formatted and transformed to a layout so it could be unambiguously asserted:

```
const Dummy = () => {
  const app = getApp();
  return <div>
    <div data-testid="app-id">{app.id}</div>
    <div data-testid="app-name">{app.name}</div>
  </div>;
};

const wrapper = mount(<Dummy/>);
expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="app-id"]').text()).toBe('mocked id');
expect(wrapper.find('[data-testid="app-name"]').text()).toBe('mocked name');
```

Where `data-testid` attribute is a convention used by other testing libraries, notably [Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bytestid) that is suitable for this kind of gray-box tests.

Comment: an answer should display how to test a selector

Comment: Should it? The answer is quite clear about that, *(state) => state.appState.app function is a selector, it can be extracted and tested separately, but since it's simple, it can be tested together with getApp*. To make it even more clear, **a selector inside useSelector hook cannot be tested directly, it requires the code to be refactored to do that**. If you had a specific difficulty with the post, you could ask about it. Thanks for the vote.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, Estus. Have you tried to use `resultFunc` for testing selectors in isolation?